# I'm using Securesocial & Play framework. I got a bug when using this

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

i got a bug when using securesocial. Form Action in template when genarate it show my IP in url,
working on localhost url is `http://localhost:9005/authenticate/userpass,` but when im put this on sever domain  i got a bug

```
<form action="http://192.168.1.100:9005/authenticate/userpass" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
```

Please help me how to fix it, I want to replace IP with hostname example http://test.mysecuresocial.com/authenticate/userpass

Comment: Showing us the result doesn't help, how about showing us the part which creates this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/authenticate/userpass" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
```

it will automatically detect, if your program is on web then it will take the hostname and at your pc it will take localhost